# UIAlertController Using a Helper Class in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm using a helper class for a couple of functions including a UIAlertController which can be accessed from elsewhere within my app, I'm having problems accessing it from within the helper class itself though.

```
func showAlert(title: String, msg: String, controller: UIViewController) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

From outside the class I can call it with no problems:

```
Helper.helper.showAlert(title: "Not Internet Detected", msg: "Data Connectivity is Required", controller: self)
```

However from within the class I get an error:

```
showAlert(title: "Email in use, did you use another method to register", msg: "please try again", controller: self)
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot convert value of type `Helper` to expected type `UIViewController`

How do I resolve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You have to pass an `UIViewController` instance as third parameter. `self` within the `Helper` class is `Helper` not `UIViewController`. That's what the compiler is complaining about. The alert can only be presented from a view controller.

Consider to use an extension of `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You can call the method in any class which inherits from `UIViewController`.